# react /redux app - add to cart button not working -when clicking TypeError: showing

Tags: reactjs, redux, ecmascript-6, react-redux, redux-toolkit

hi guys I am  creating a react app using redux tool kit ,
trying to add a add to cart function and when when clicking add to cart button the error msg pops up saying

### below is the error massage

```
×
TypeError: addTocart is not a function
onClick
src/Cardshild.js:17
  14 |   <div > <img className="proimg" src={add.image} /></div>
  15 |   <div> {add.title}</div>
  16 |   <div> {add.price}</div>
> 17 |   <button onClick={() => addTocart(add)} carditems={carditems} >
     | ^  18 |       add to cart
  19 |   </button>
  20 | </div>
```

**below is my parent component**

---

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { selectAddSlice } from "./features/auth/addsSlice";
import Cardshild from './Cardshild'


const Addtocart = (props) => {

  const [cartit, setCardItems] = useState([])
  
  const selectedAdds = useSelector(selectAddSlice);
  const addTocart = () => {
    const cartItems = selectedAdds.slice();
    let alreadyincart = false
    cartItems.forEach((item) => {           
        if(item._id === add._id){
            item.count++;
             alreadyincart = true
        }         
    })
    if(!alreadyincart){
        setCardItems({...add, count:1})
        console.log(add + "dsdsadsdasfdfdfd")
       
    }    
   
        setCardItems(cartit)
      
}

  return (
    <div className="pro__wrapper">
      {selectedAdds.map((add, i) => (
        <Cardshild addTocart={addTocart} key={i} add={add} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Addtocart;
```

---

below is the child component which I am trying to output the numbers when add to cart button clicked

```
import React from 'react'

const CardItems = ({carditems}) => {
    return (
        <div>
           {carditems.count}
        </div>
    )
}

export default CardItems
```

**this is redux slice file**

---

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import alladds from './adds.json'

export const dataSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'addlist',
    initialState: {
        alladd: alladds.products
    },
    reducers: {   
    },
});

export const { addalladds } = dataSlice.actions;

export const selectAddSlice = state => state.addlist.alladd

export default dataSlice.reducer;
```

cardshild component

---

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import CardItems from './features/auth/CardItems'

const Cardshild = ({add, addTocart}) => {
    //const [amount, setamount] = useState(add.quantity)
    const [carditems, setCardItems] = useState([])
    
   
    return (
        <div className="cardshild">
          <div>
                
            <div key={add._id}>
              <div > <img className="proimg" src={add.image} /></div>
              <div> {add.title}</div>
              <div> {add.price}</div>
              <button onClick={() => addTocart(add)} carditems={carditems} >
                  add to cart
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div>
            <CardItems carditems={carditems} />
          </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Cardshild
```

below is json data

---

```
{
    "products": [
        {
          "_id": "1",
          "image": "url",
          "price": 29.9
        },
        {
            "_id": "2",
            "image": "url",
            "price": 63.1
          },
          {
            "_id": "3",
            "image": "url",
            "price": 59
          }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Please share Your CardShild component code.

Comment: Can you reproduce that in a sandbox?

Comment: Why do you have your carditems inside your cart? Also when you click the button and call the addToCart method you pass a parameter and in your method definition you don't receive any parameter.. Maybe that's your problem.

Comment: @Filipe can u suggest any method to recieve the parameter

Comment: @Domino987 I tried but could not litte bit hard for me to setup

Comment: @famo const addTocart = (add) => {...}. You're are using "add" inside of that function but it's not defined anywhere.

Comment: I see No reason why you would get **TypeError: addTocart is not a function** because it is well-defined in Parent component and passed to child component, and it is a function. Can you write `console.log(addTocart)` in `Cardshild` component? `button` doesn't need `carditems={carditems}`. try removing that.

Comment: @Filipe inside Addtocart.js           {selectedAdds.map((add, i) => (
            <Cardshild addTocart={addTocart} key={i} add={add} />
          ))} i am getting the add is it a wrong way to get

Comment: @AjeetShah added console inside return its undefined

Comment: Inside `addToCart` the line `item.count++` is a mutation of state because you are dealing with a shallow copy.  But I'm not yet seeing why the function would be undefined.  A CodeSandbox demo would help a lot.

Comment: I never did reproduce your error but I got this working by using redux instead of local state https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-kilby-x16ok?file=/src/Cardshild.js

Comment: @LindaPaiste can add as the answer ? ill choose

Comment: @Filipe  I ahve another question please check my wall if possible

Comment: @AjeetShah I have another question please check wall if possible